# Injectivity of locally free sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $F$, $G$ be two locally free sheaf on $X$, and let $\phi:F\rightarrow G$ is injective. Then why is that $\phi$ may not be injective on all fibers? Are we still regarding this map as morphism of sheafs, so injective should be equivalent to injective on all fibres?

Comment: There is a difference between stalks and fiber. The injectivity at the level of stalks is indeed equivalent to the injectivity of the sheaf morphism. But an injective morphism may fail to be fiberwise injective.

Comment: @Roland Aha, so a fibre means the base extension over $k(x)$, not the germ. I see my problem.

Comment: I do not know why you think it has to be true.. I am not very comfortable in these topics but for a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, the fiber at a point $x\in X$ is $\mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_x}k(x)$ where $\mathcal{F}_x$ is stalk of $\mathcal{F}$ at $x$, $\mathcal{O}_x$ is stalk of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ at $x$ and $k(x)$ is the residue field of  $\mathcal{O}_x$... Isn't it so?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Not really, it should be the pullback along the morphism of $k(x)\rightarrow X$ to the point $x$. What you consider is not in general true, but it is true if it is a closed point. I thought it is right is just as Roland's comment, I thought it is the germ. But suppose you take generic point, then it will be totally a different story.